# Redirect stderr on screen and a file, stdout on the same file only

Tags: bash

I'm trying to redirect:

- stderr: screen, file output.txt
- stdout: same file output.txt only

for a cron job.

The goal I'm trying to achieve is getting notified only when there are errors, while logging the whole output to a file.

The email message should include those error messages, because in many cases I'm able to recognize and fix the issue just by reading error messages. I need to get notified about all kind of errors. The script prints its own errors on stderr too.

I need to log the whole output on the same file, because is useful to know what the script was doing when the error was thrown.

Already existing log files must be truncated.

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

```
exec 4>output.log; ./script 2> >(tee >(cat - >&4)) 1>&4
```

Notes:

- Using a file descriptor is mandatory to avoid race conditions when using tee on the same file where `stdout` is already redirected;
- `exec 4>output.log` and not `exec 4<>output.log` otherwise the file won't be truncated;
- `tee >(cat - >&4)` is the syntax to pass a file descriptor rather than a filename to such command;
- `2> >(tee ...)` is the syntax to redirect stderr to tee command